# Apple Wi-Fi Dropping at Random Times

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi

I'm sure that my Wi-Fi router is fine because my MacBook is the only one with this issue.  I see this happen especially when I use Skype, FaceTime, etc.  This has been going on for a month and can't really find a fix.

I did see that OS X 10.7 Lion has some connectivity issue but don't think it has been solved.  I have tried many tips told by other users.  I hope someone from here can help me.

I get an error saying  "Connection Timeout".

Thank You

Comment: You've used Wi-Fi Diagnostics.app (in System/Library/Core Services) to monitor signal/noise over time? There may be some new noise source in your neighborhood that's intermittently interfering with your signal.

Comment: I ran the tool... looks like its fine.

Comment: What router are you using?